# Blazor: The type or namespace name 'ApplicationPartAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am getting this error when I try to compile my Blazor WebAssembly app.

`error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ApplicationPartAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

The reason is because I am using a library which uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` and it seems to not to be very compatible with blazor Web Assembly,

I did tested creating a server side blazor app and It works fine.

Is there any way to make the error "dissapear"? I would like to use that library and I would like to stick with Blazor WA.

Comment: I get this kind of thing all the time.  VS Intellisense in Blazor is a buggy mess, and I think for now we just have to accept it.

Comment: Which version of the Asp.net Core are you using?  From the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationparts.applicationpartattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0), we can see that the class name should be `ApplicationPartAttribute`, instead of `ApplicationPartAttributeAttribute` (the `attribute` is duplicate). And the `ApplicationPartAttribute` class applies to Asp.net Core 3.0, 3.1, 5.0.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 yes, seems like it, as it was an internal library I ended up splitting it in two, but I'm worried something like that happen with a bigger library :/

Comment: @ZhiLv Im using net5; my main concern is why does it work in blazor serverside and not in WA.

Comment: Which library?  MVC stuff just isn't applicable to WebAssembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27373) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26724), I'd advise that you not reference razor class library with support for pages and views or reference a library that targets ASP.NET Core. That is not going to work in Blazor Webassembly.

My suggestion is that you factor out the classes you directly need to reference from your shared library and use them in your wasm project, without making reference to the entire library, you could even factor those classes and create a new library to be referenced to without any dependencies on asp.net core framework.

An excerpt from one of the links I pasted said: "Thanks for contacting us. This is not a pattern we recommend to follow. You can't reference MVC binaries from a Blazor WebAssembly application."

Answer (score 0):

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name
> 'ApplicationPartAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts' (are you missing an
> assembly reference?)

First, from the official document, we can see that the class name should be `ApplicationPartAttribute`, instead of `ApplicationPartAttributeAttribute` (the `attribute` is duplicate).Please check your code and modify it.

> my main concern is why does it work in blazor serverside and not in
> WA.

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts` package work in Blazor server side and not in WA application.

For this issue, I assume you are creating a **primary Blazor hosting model** or **standalone Blazor WebAssembly** app, for this kind of application, it is **client-side** and without a backend ASP.NET Core app to serve its files, so you can't use the `ApplicationParts`.

But, if you create a **hosted Blazor WebAssembly app**: when create the WebAssembly application, selected the "ASP.NET Core hosted" option.

[image]

After that, the Blazor WebAssembly application looks as below:

[image]

As we can see, the application contains three projects, and then we could use the `ApplicationParts` in the server project. so, you could create a hosted Blazor WebAssembly app.

More detail information, see [Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-webassembly).

Comment: Unfortunatelly this solution does not fix my issue, I do have a client and a server, but on the client I have to access `Wrapper<T> ` this wrapper is in a library that uses the mvc.core package. I ended up splitting up the library. Also note the issue with the name in `ApplicationPartAttributeAttribute ` this is autogenerated so I don't really know why it creates it like that.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents.

I have a blazor Wasm app, and getting the following error.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'ApplicationPartAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Mewurk.Hrms.Support.BlazorWasm  D:\Mewurk\AdminConsole\src\Mewurk.Hrms.Support.BlazorWasm\obj\Debug\net6.0\Mewurk.Hrms.Support.BlazorWasm.MvcApplicationPartsAssemblyInfo.cs    14  Active

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'ApplicationPartAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  Mewurk.Hrms.Support.BlazorWasm  D:\Mewurk\AdminConsole\src\Mewurk.Hrms.Support.BlazorWasm\obj\Debug\net6.0\Mewurk.Hrms.Support.BlazorWasm.MvcApplicationPartsAssemblyInfo.cs    14  Active

I am getting the above error, after I add a reference to a .net core 6 class library project which holds the following nuget package.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.0.8" />
```

As it turns out, the class library project does not need that. So I removed and the error vanished.